# Add a post when another post type is inserting

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks, actions, wp-insert-post

I want to add a product when service post type inserting or updating. Below is the code. It works but it keep generates products while the code executing. What is the wrong with this code?

```
add_action( 'publish_service', function( $post_id, $post ){
    add_action('wp_after_insert_post', function($post_id, $post, $update){
        $product_exist = get_field('product_id', $post_id) ? true : false;
        // write_log($post_exist);
        if($product_exist){
            // Clear variations
            $product = wc_get_product(get_field('product_id', $post_id));
             foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $variation){
                wc_get_product($variation['variation_id'])->delete();
            }
        }
        $plans = get_field('plans', $post_id);
        // write_log($product_exist);
        $product = $product_exist ? wc_get_product(get_field('product_id', $post_id)) : create_service_product($post->post_title); // HERE IS ERROR WHILE CREATING PRODUCTS
    }, 10, 3);
}, 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code appears to be related to the hook `wp_after_insert_post` being nested within the publish_service action. This setup can lead to the `wp_after_insert_post` action being added multiple times, which may cause the repeated creation of products.

**Here are a few steps to resolve this issue:**

**Separate the Actions:** Instead of nesting `wp_after_insert_post` within publish_service, consider separating them. This will prevent the inner action from being registered multiple times.

**Check for Post Type:** Ensure that the code runs only for the 'service' post type. This prevents the code from running for other post types.

**Avoid Infinite Loops:** When updating a post within a hook that triggers on post save or update, you must prevent an infinite loop. This can be done by removing the action before making changes to the post and then re-adding it afterward.

**Product Creation and Updating Logic:** Make sure your logic for creating or updating the product is correct. This includes checking if the product already exists and updating it if necessary, or creating a new one if it doesn't.

**Here is an updated version of your code considering these points:**

```
add_action( 'publish_service', function( $post_id, $post ) {
    if ( 'service' !== get_post_type( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $product_exist = get_field('product_id', $post_id) ? true : false;

    if ($product_exist) {
        // Logic for updating the existing product
        $product = wc_get_product(get_field('product_id', $post_id));
        foreach ($product->get_available_variations() as $variation) {
            wc_get_product($variation['variation_id'])->delete();
        }
    } else {
        // Logic for creating a new product
        create_service_product($post->post_title);
    }

    // Your additional logic here (like handling plans)
}, 10, 2);

function create_service_product($post_title) {
    // Logic for creating a new WooCommerce product
    // Return the new product ID or object
}
```

In this updated code:

The action is only attached to `publish_service`.
The product creation or update logic is executed directly in the `publish_service` action.
It checks if the post type is 'service' before proceeding.
The separate function `create_service_product` is assumed to handle the creation of a new product.
Remember to test this on a staging environment first before deploying it to a live site.

Comment: You are write but it's not possible to access meta values in publish_service hook. And why we need extra validation you wrote at the very first, if not service then return.